# Can Mathematica autogenerate package files with the extension .wl instead of .m?

Tags: packages

I have Mathematica 12.1 running on macOS Catalina. The .m file has forever been a problem on macOS, which assumes that .m belongs to Objective C.

I always autogenerate package files from notebooks, using the setting "Options Inspector" > "Notebook Options" > "File Options" > AutoGeneratedPackage, but I can't find anyplace in either Preferences or the Options Inspector to control the extension Mathematica uses.

Comment: Do you use Objective C? If not, you can assign .m to Mathematica without any inconveniences.

Comment: @Szabolcs, not right now, but I do plan to do macOS/iOS dev in the future, so I don't want to co-opt the extension right now. Even though I intend to use Swift, I'm afraid some Objective C might get sucked in somewhere along the way.

Comment: I use .m both with Mathematica and MATLAB and do not find it a huge inconvenience ...

Comment: In particular, if you use auto-generated packages, there is no reason to open them directly. You would only load them with `Get` but you would not open them by double-clicking. So I do not see how this would be a problem.

Comment: Of course, the question is still a good one. However, I do hope that Wolfram will not unilaterally change the default to `.wl` without giving an option to control it, as it would break existing setups.

Comment: You have a good point. My issue stems primarily from an ongoing effort to clean up old unwise symbol naming conventions I used in the past. When I update a source notebook, I use system-wide text searches for references. I currently search `.m`, `.nb` and `.wl` files. But the `.nb` obviates the need to search its auto-generated `.m`. So all I really need to do is rename all my manually created `.m` files and remove that extension from my search set.

Thanks for making me reevaluate an entrenched habit in light of new information.